# how can I remove registered .tpl.php file?

Tags: theming

When I remove html.tpl.php file, I get this error:

```
Warning: include(/home/xxxx/public_html/sites/all/themes/cgame/html.tpl.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in theme_render_template() (line 1413 of /home/xxxx/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/xxxx/public_html/sites/all/themes/cgame/html.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in theme_render_template() (line 1413 of /home/xxxx/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
```

How can I remove this file to force drupal use core html.tpl.php file?

Comment: Clear the caches, that should do it

Comment: When I remove html.tpl.php file I get WSOD and I even can not access to clear cache page

Comment: Which *core* `html.tpl.php` file are you actually talking about?

Comment: I need remove sites/all/themes/cgame/html.tpl.php and use modules/system/html.tpl.php instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering `White Screen of Death` problem you should clear cache from DB or change default theme to another theme so can clear cache from drupal admin interface, if you have access to DB first solution is easier and fast but in case you don't, use second one :

1.truncate `cache` table:

```
TRUNCATE cache;
```

2.set another default theme so you can clear cache from `admin/config/development/performance` page.
you can simply edit `settings.php` and add `$conf['theme_default']= "new_theme_name"` variable to change default theme or edit `variables` table in DB and set `theme_default` name to another name, sample SQL:

```
UPDATE variable SET value='s:7:"garland"' WHERE name = 'theme_default';
```

then while this new theme is set you can clear cache as usual and then fallback to old theme without problem.

Comment: ;) I was looking for something like `theme registry editor` to simply remove `html.tpl.php` from default theme, but there isn't

Answer (score 1):

Simply clear the caches either on */admin/config/development/performance* or via *drush cc all* if you've configured drush.